# Four jQuery date time pickers

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I'm using the Jquery date time picker [link here](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/)

In the four methods below I am initializing the DT pickers but they are all pretty similar except for the ID in the `onChangeDateTime`.

Is there a way I can reduce the duplicate code?

```
$('.jqDatetimeDateOne').datetimepicker({
    defaultTime: '07:00',
    lang: 'en',
    className: 'setTimeClicker',
    step: 30,
    onChangeDateTime: function (current_time, $input) {
        // alert(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'))
        $('#emailGenDateOne').removeClass('empty').val(current_time.dateFormat('Y-m-d H:i'));
    },
    inline: true
});

$('.jqDatetimeDateTwo').datetimepicker({
    defaultTime: '07:00',
    lang: 'en',
    className: 'setTimeClicker',
    step: 30,
    onChangeDateTime: function (current_time, $input) {
        // alert(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'))
        $('#emailGenDateTwo').removeClass('empty').val(current_time.dateFormat('Y-m-d H:i'));
    },
    inline: true
});

$('.jqDatetimeSearchDateOne').datetimepicker({
    defaultTime: '07:00',
    lang: 'en',
    className: 'setTimeClicker',
    step: 30,
    onChangeDateTime: function (current_time, $input) {
        // alert(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'))
        $('#searchGenDateOne').removeClass('empty').val(current_time.dateFormat('Y-m-d H:i'));
    },
    inline: true
});

$('.jqDatetimeSearchDateTwo').datetimepicker({
    defaultTime: '07:00',
    lang: 'en',
    className: 'setTimeClicker',
    step: 30,
    onChangeDateTime: function (current_time, $input) {
        // alert(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'))
        $('#searchGenDateTwo').removeClass('empty').val(current_time.dateFormat('Y-m-d H:i'));
    },
    inline: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

So:

```
function configureDateTimePicker(selector1,selector2)
{
    $(selector1).datetimepicker(
    {
        defaultTime: '07:00',
        lang: 'en',
        className: 'setTimeClicker',
        step: 30,
        onChangeDateTime: function (current_time, $input)
        {
            // alert(ct.dateFormat('d/m/Y'))
            $(selector2).removeClass('empty').val(current_time.dateFormat('Y-m-d H:i'));
        },
        inline: true
    });
}

configureDateTimePicker('.jqDatetimeDateOne','#emailGenDateOne');
configureDateTimePicker('.jqDatetimeDateTwo','#emailGenDateTwo');
configureDateTimePicker('.jqDatetimeSearchDateOne','#searchGenDateOne');
configureDateTimePicker('.jqDatetimeSearchDateTwo','#searchGenDateTwo');
```

There could be further optimisations if you changed your classes/ids so that one could be derived from the other or from a common string (e.g. if they were all `.jqDatetimeSomething` and `#genSomething`). Or if there's a way to find the one of the targets through their relationship in the DOM (e.g. one is a descendant of the other matching a given selector).